# Hiding DAO functionality behind Web Services

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Does splitting-up a standard .NET MVC webapp into a "Front End" (controllers & services) and "Back End" (DAOs hidden behind a web service) automatically make it more secure? The "Back End" would be deployed on another "more secure" server.

Why is it more secure? Assuming the "Front End" was as secure as it could possibly be, and a hacker still managed to break in, wouldn't it be fairly easy for them to then push through to the "Back End" anyway even if the WS calls were done over SSL too, because the FrontEnd has now been compromised?

It sounds like it *should* be more secure (and it's what I'm being told at work by our architects), but I'm struggling to understand exactly what it is about this split-approach that would make the hacker (who has already infiltrated the "Front End") think he had hit a brick wall and could go no further.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not more secure - it's not less, but it's not more either. Splitting up the front-end from the backend is good practice because of separation of concerns, abstraction of business logic, etc., but it has nothing to do with security.

Comment: Thanks, I can understand splitting it up for design reasons but every time I ask why, I just get told: "for security". Our apps are not huge and dont need to be clustered or load-balanced so our standard controller/service/DAO is usually good enough. And we could split them up later if we needed to anyway. Just seems like a lot (well, a bit) of extra work for no additional security benefit.